# Wordpress: Synchronization of Plugin Data

Tags: wordpress, plugins, synchronization, hook

I try to make a Wordpress-Site which has kind of a rich functionality.
My approach is, to use existing Plugins to contain the neede Functions in my Website.
It is really possible, to find a plugin for every function, since they are kind of common.
But the problem is the following:
The domain-logic of my site is not really covered by the plugins, since it needs a data synchronization between several different singel plugins.
For example: I have a file manager and a calendar. I want to (the user should be able to) select files from the manager and display them as events in the calendar (one simple example).

So i wonder how i could more or less professionally synchronize data between different plugins and map domain-logic into my datasets / database.

At the moment, i would use Hooks as triggers and write some functions to synchronize the data, perhaps SQL-scripts would be needed. So the "Logic" would be in the triggered functions.
But if i do so: How would i implement this in a more or less simple way? I think i don't really have the time to write an entire plugin "Synchronizer" by myself.

I also thought about working with database triggers and manipulate the data directly. But isn't this dangerous, to intervent in the internal database and functions of wordpress? I don't relly like this idea.

Or should I use the REST-API? I think this would be wrong...

So: What possibilities do i have to implement my logic / sync in a more or less simple respectively not so "expensive" way? I know, the the amount of work will depend from the complexity of my logic, but i wanna keep things as simple as possible. (is there any standard-way to do this?)

I'm kind of stumped...

Thanks for your help.
kind regards
Riemann

I did not implement anything at the moment.
I try to make a good concept of the architecture for my site now.
And I'm no real wordpress-crack...

Comment: The devil's in the details for a project like this. There's no general way to synchronize data between various plugins, because they all work differently.  Many use WordPress's wp_posts and wp_postmeta database tables to store their content. If you can write your own plugin code to wrangle data in those tables, you may be able to do some of this. Unfortunately your question is very vague and difficult to answer as written.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the question is a bit vague, becaus the project is "young". So I'm at the beginning of the development process and looking for a good solution which should be possible implement. I'm also not sure, if it's the best solution to use several different plugins and try to synchronize them later. perhaps this is an architectural issue in this case. I'm just looking for some good and new information to make a step forward. At the moment, it's more about the concept of the site, less about "the devil in the details". But I understand your answer -> this is valuable information!

Comment: I guess I was trying to be polite about existing plugins. To be blunt, they have all sorts of different ways of handling their data, and all sorts of coding and quality standards, from very sloppy to great. There are a couple of big plugin ecosystems: one is BuddyPress and another is WooCommerce. Those might be worth your time to investigate.